# mysql where 10 < id < 20

Tags: mysql

i am going to select some certain ids from db. my logic is this: depending on hour, i am selecting some certain items like this, because the job is running in cronjob, and it runs every `*:31` minutes, so every hour, this is my logic:

pseudo code:

```
get hour // 08:30
take 08 and mult(08,10); // 80 
get items from db whose ids lie between 80 < id < 90
```

how can i do this query in mysql? this `80 < id < 90` condition i need in mysql in php

Comment: try this way by using AND in the  where 80 < id AND id<90

Comment: Hover over the downvote arrow for a clue.  This question shows no research effort.  You haven't shown us what you've tried and what hasn't worked, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the keyword `between`

```
select * from tableName where id between 80 AND 90
```

Answer (score 2):

Translating your pseudo code into SQL with exact the same behavior as described

> 80 < id < 90

leads to

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id BETWEEN 80+1 AND 90-1
```

Because `WHERE` include the bounds

or straight

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 80 < id AND id < 90
```